# PHP json, finding info and linking it with 4chan api

Tags: php, json, api

If I wanted to echo the link of a general thread on 4chan.

Here's what I was thinking of, however I have no idea on what to do

```
$jsonurl = "http://a.4cdn.org/vg/catalog.json";
$json = file_get_contents($jsonurl);
$json_output = json_decode($json);

foreach( $json_output as $no )
{
    if(strpos(sub, 'DOTA')) { //Not sure how I would do this
        //echo the "no" of it in the json
    }
}
```

Comment: Why `$a` at all? `$a` is defined nowhere. "strpos($a, 'DOTA')" cannot work as long as you keep it in double-quotes. As for the rest, i'm sorry - from the code you provided i cannot tell.

Comment: Ahh. I really didn't know what I was doing. Fixing. Kind of

Comment: *sub* alone won't get you anywhere. See, using *foreach* you are iterating over all the elements in the current level of $json_output. Therefore $no will contain the current element for each time the loop is played out. So i assume what you want is strstr($no, 'DOTA')

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Had to look at the JSON data to see what you were looking for. Give this a try

```
$jsonurl = "http://a.4cdn.org/g/catalog.json";
$json = file_get_contents($jsonurl);
$json_output = json_decode($json);

foreach ($json_output as $page) {
    foreach($page->threads as $thread) {
        if (isset($thread->sub)) {
            $sub = $thread->sub;
            $no  = $thread->no;

            echo $sub . ', Thread Number: ' . $no . '<br />';

            /*
            if (strpos($sub, 'DOTA') !== false) {
                echo 'Found DOTA!!! Thread Number is: ' . $thread->no;
            } 
            */
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When changing it to /g/ and "Daily Programming Thread", I get nothing. Do you possibly know why? It throws `Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$sub `

Comment: I tried `if(isset($thread->sub))` and it removes the error, yet does not get the post no (if that helps)

Comment: Hmm. So I guess I should be working on com, not sub. I have it somewhat working, yet I noticed that the `$json_output[0]`, at least for /g/, makes it only view the first "page", even though all the information is in the json, because when I replace it with 2 and search, it will find it if it's on the second page.

So I have it how I want, thank you, but is there a way for $threads to be `$json_output[everything]->threads;`

Answer (score -1):

You should study the JSON data that you receive in order to know how to extract the data. This is one way of doing it:

```
foreach( $json_output as $page ) {
  foreach ($page->threads as $t) { 
    echo 'http://boards.4chan.org/vg/res/' . $t->no . ', ';
  }
}
```